# Jquery autocomplete change source based on input value prefix

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete

I have 2 remote php scripts as data sources and I want to call each based on the user input prefix.
I could not find how to do that with jquery autocomplete or with javascript.
I will probably need to call a regex function to decide which data source to use.

I am getting the user input from regular form text field:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#srv_search').autocomplete({
                            source:'srv_search.php',
                            minLength:2});
            });
    </script>
            <form action="site.php" method="post">
                    <input type="text" id="srv_search" name="server" value="" style="width: 80%;">
                    <input type="submit" value="Go">
            </form>
```

Thanks,
David

PS, this is what I tried based on the reply and doesn't work:

```
$('#srv_search').autocomplete({
                            minLength:2,
                            source: function(request, response) {
                                    var usearch = request;
                                    var upatt = new RegExp(/^f[0-9]/);
                                    if (upatt.test(usearch)) {
                                            var dataSource = "srv_search.php";
                                    }
                                    else {
                                            var dataSource = "des_search.php";
                                    }
                                    $.get(dataSource, {term: request}, response);
                                    }
                    });
```

Comment: Why not handle the logic server side in a controller instead of through javascript

Comment: Great question. I did, but the results are not rendered as expected. on FF and Chrom, on IE it worked. So I'm trying to filter from the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `source: someFn`

Where

```
someFn = function(request, response) {
    // request["term"] = Text entered by User
    // Choose your data source based on it.

    var dataSource = /* whatever */;
    $.getJson(dataSource, request, response);

    // or $.get(dataSource, request, response);
    // basically response is to be used as callback
}
```

**PS**: It's untested, just wrote quick code to nudge you in the right direction. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks, please note that I edited my initial post with your suggested code, and it did not worked for me. I probably miss something... thanks again.

Comment: @DavidPeer, Edited original answer to fix... actually request is already of the format `{term: "whatever"}`. See working example here - http://jsfiddle.net/qePj2/ (use browser console to see request being made)